# Leave it in/on or keep it on?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct?

> (1) Do not unplug the charger. Just ***leave it in***.
>
> (2) Do not unplug the charger. Just ***leave it on***.
>
> (3) Do not unplug the charger. Just ***keep it on***.

Thanks!

Comment: It's actually a reminder using a picture on the wall at my office. It's in Bahasa Indonesia. It says "Dilarang Cabut. Kasih tinggal saja," which is translated into English as "Do not unplug the charger. Leave it in/ on/ keep it on."

Comment: I think "leave it in" would be the best as the statement is concerning the physical location of the charger being plugged into a wall. If the charger has a switch and you are telling a person not to turn it off by using the switch then you would use leave it on.

Answer (score 0):

*(2) Do not unplug the charger. Just LEAVE IT ON.*

Of your three options, this is the least bad one.  However:

- The use of "just" is not common format in this context.
- "Do not unplug the charger." and "Just LEAVE IT ON." mean the same thing, so is it necessary to use both?
- Having LEAVE IT ON in Caps looks like a rude shout ... it's not needed.

I would probably just say "Do not unplug the charger until your device is fully charged.", or whatever the actual technical requirements are. Keep it simple and polite.